# Using min-height and max-height at the same time

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have to upload images in my app ( i'm using react and styled-components in the fronted ), and, i want the size of the img to be at least 25vh and max 140vh, so this is how i made the code

```
export const ShowPhoto = styles.div`

width: 614px;
min-height: 25vh;
max-height: 140vh;

margin-top: 3rem;


img{
    width: 614px;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

`;
```

As you can see, the img is inside the container.

**So, my question is**: Is this a good way to do it? i've never used min-height and max-height at the same time, so, am i breaking a css rule or something? or it's ok the way i did it?

Thansk for your time !

Comment: 'is this a good way to do it' - it depends on what effect is required. What do you want to happen if the img at the given width is far to tall for the container or conversely far too small? I'm not clear who is to define the height, the div container or the img itself.

Comment: I want the height of the img to be min 25vh and max 140vh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the height of the containing div needs to be dictated by the aspect ratio of the img. So putting the min and max heights on the container rather than the content does not give the desired result in all situations.

Moving min and max height to the img, making the img 100% width of the container and asking for an object-fit gives the result that the image will always have the width of the container, if possible it will show completely but if that is not possible then object-fit cover is invoked with the container taking on the relevant min or max height.

With two images of differing aspect ratios this snippet produced this on my laptop, with the top img shown completely, and the bottom cropped to fit the max height. Of course it depends on the height of the viewport versus that of the img when it has width 614px as to what result is obtained:

[image]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    width: 614px;

    margin-top: 3rem;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 25vh;
    max-height: 140vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/100"/>
  <br><br>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/600"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you are a legend ! that's what i was looking for !